# Only allow whitelisted users to run certain commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I just want to make a command only runnable if the `ctx.message.author.id` is found in a list of whitelisted users.

What I tried:

```
whitelisted = [1213712316,131723171,...]

@bot.command()
async def checkwl(ctx):
   if ctx.message.author in whitelisted:
      await ctx.send("you are whitelisted")
      ...
   else:
      await ctx.send("Sorry but you are not whitelisted")
```

Comment: Okay... What happened?

Comment: A little more context would be good @nullbody.

Comment: A quick look at the docs on Discord Server shows it has a permissions model baked in. I would suggest you build on that capability.

Answer (score -2):

This Question has been posted on a Discord Server(by the author ofc).

New Code :

````
whitelisted = [1213712316,131723171,...]

@bot.command()
async def checkwl(ctx):
   if int(ctx.message.author.id) in whitelisted:
      await ctx.send("you are whitelisted")
      ...
   else:
      await ctx.send("Sorry but you are not whitelisted")```
````